# How to debug my simple Excel VBA macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm just trying to check the latest Date cell, which is in Column A, against the current date. If the difference is 30 days, I write a new row.

When I execute, it says I can't call CheckAttendance on Sheet("Occurences"). But why?

```
    Option Explicit

    Public LastCell As Long
    Public today As Date


    Function CheckAttendance()

        Dim DaysSinceOcc As Integer

        'returns last occupied row
        LastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'gets current date
        today = Date

        'subtracts last cell in specified column from today's date.
        DaysSinceOcc = today - Cells(LastCell, 1).Value

        'writes what I want written in the cells I want it written in.        
        If DaysSinceOcc > 29 Then
            Cells(LastCell, 1).Offset(1, 1) = "winback"
            Cells(LastCell, 1).Offset(1, 2) = -0.5
            Cells(LastCell, 1).Offset(1, 4) = "Earned back 0.5 pts for 30 days perfect attendance (AutoGenerated)"
            Cells(LastCell, 1).Offset(1, 5) = "AUTO"
            Cells(LastCell, 1).Offset(1, 0) = today
        Else

        End If


    End Function

    Sub Attendance()

        Sheets("Occurences").CheckAttendance
        'yes Occurences is suppose to be spelled like that (don't ask)

    End Sub
```

edit: there are probably multiple problems with this. I fixed a lot of things, but then got stuck.

Comment: just `CheckAttendance` without `Sheets("Occurences").`

Comment: in addition to @Slai's comment: 1) it should be a sub, not function; 2) you need to provide a proper reference to Cells in your code (explicitly reference workbook and worksheet, otherwise your code might be unstable)

Comment: @RADO Thanks for your comment. My understanding of your comment compared to the A.S.H. answer is that I have two different options: make the worksheet a parameter, which allows the sub to be called on different worksheets, OR I can make it more specific, so that it only works on my Occurences sheet. Am I understanding that correctly, or are those options not mutually exclusive like I think they are?

Comment: A.S.H. gave you a solid advice. I was referring to the fact that your code contained unqualified reference to Cells(), which is dangerous because it essentially means: ActiveBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(). If your code starts running in non-active book, or your sheet is no longer active, it will either crash or lead to unexpected results. If you look at A.S.H code, he preceds every Cell with ws. (worksheet object). Re: parameter or hard-coded sheet name - the choice is dictated by your goals. If you need to do the same operation on many sheets, use parameter. Otherwise, just use the sheet name.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! Much appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the best, correct answer. In addition to rewarding the answerer with reputation, your also get +2 added to yours.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to parametrize your `CheckAttendance` routine so that it can be called on different worksheets. To do that, make it a `Sub` that takes a worksheet as parameter. Moreover

- qualify you cells and ranges in the code
- dim your variables and use `Option Explicit`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckAttendance(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim DaysSinceOcc As Long, lastRow As Long, today As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    'gets current date
    today = Date

    'subtracts last cell in specified column from today's date.
    DaysSinceOcc = today - ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value2

    'writes what I want written in the cells I want it written in.
    If DaysSinceOcc > 29 Then
        ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1) = today
        ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2) = "winback"
        ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 3) = -0.5
        ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 5) = "Earned back 0.5 pts for 30 days perfect attendance (AutoGenerated)"
        ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 6) = "AUTO"
    End If
End Sub

Sub Attendance()
    CheckAttendance Sheets("Occurences") ' <-- this is how you call it on any worksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.
With the Variables--Dim vs. Public:
I was under the impression that you should use Public if you want to be able to use the variable in other macros in the same book. In my mind VBA-Public = python-global.  Is that correct?
What is the rationale for making all the variables local?

Comment: @ChristopherGraves we have no public variables in this snippet, only locals. Public/global variables are declared *outside routine* and aim to be accessible by many routines. By the principles of *data hiding* (aka encapsulation), they are to avoid unless really necessary. Why? because they tend to make the code more difficult to track and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your help!